# My suffix is feeling certain, I make you feel uncertain

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix uses a force.
>
> My suffix is feeling certain.
>
> My infix is a legal force.
>
> I make you feel uncertain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Pressure

My prefix uses a force.

> **Press**

My suffix is feeling certain.

> **Sure**

My infix is a legal force.

> **Su** sounds like "sue"

I make you feel uncertain.

> Pressure can mean the use of persuasion or intimidation to make someone do something.